# css vertical drop down menu like wascc.com.au

Tags: html, css, menu

I would like to create a CSS vertical menu like the one active @ http://www.wascc.com.au/

However, I am converting this website to Wordpress, so the HTML generating the menu is different to the original.

The new Wordpress site is @ http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/

This is the new Wordpress HTML menu:

```css
    ul#menu-primary-menu li {
        font: 16px/51px oswaldregular;
        color: #48391f;
        background: url(/images/navi-shap.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    ul#menu-primary-menu li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #48391f;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 25px;
    }
    .sub-menu li a {
        background: url(/images/dropdown_arrow_white.png) no-repeat center left;
        display: block;
        min-width: 110px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0px 9px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font: 12px/30px oswaldregular;
    }
    .sub-menu, .sub-menu ul {
        border-top: 3px solid #fcbb38;
        border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -o-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -ms-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 2px;
        top: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: #333333;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
   <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-67"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/committee/">Committee</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/constitution/">Constitution</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/life-members/">Life Members</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/">Calendar</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-100 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/race-calendar-2016/">Race Calendar 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/">Competition</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/categories/">Categories</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/standing-regs/">Standing Regs</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/licenses/">Licenses</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/results/">Results</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/entries/">Entries</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-87"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/">Membership</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/sign-up-for-membership/">Sign up for Membership</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/gift-cards/">Gift Cards</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-90"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/">Officials</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/accreditations/">Accreditations</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/affiliations/">Affiliations</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/disciplines/">Disciplines</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-95"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/">V8 Supercars</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/overview/">Overview</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/travel-information/">Travel Information</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/circuit-map/">Circuit Map</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/tickets-corporate/">Tickets &amp; Corporate</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-73"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/">Activities</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/bike-days/">Bike Days</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/corporate-venue-hire/">Corporate Venue Hire</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/drive-days/">Drive Days</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/karts/">Karts</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/your-car-our-track/">Your Car Our Track</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

But this needs to be added to, to complete the drop down behaviour.

Assistance appreciated.

Steve.

Comment: you did not mention where is the problem? can you show menu view now after converting wordpress?

Comment: Woops. Sorry @ChoncholMahmud . [http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/](http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention `position:relative` in `ul#menu-primary-menu li` and `display:block` in `ul#menu-primary-menu li:hover ul`

Here is the **[working code](https://jsfiddle.net/9ctdkbfk/)**

you need to adjust the other style like http://www.wascc.com.au/

Please let me know is it working for you?

Comment: Thanks @RoySonasish. I've included your CSS in my [CSS file](http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/wp-content/themes/WASCC/style.css), but the drop down menus do not work [on the live site](http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/)

Comment: Hi @RoySonasish. Modified code is now on the live site, but unfortunately the drop down menus are not displaying.

Comment: can you provide the url of live site?

Comment: please check its working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/9ctdkbfk/, why don't you follow the css from here

Comment: Hi Roy, I believe I added your code correctly to the bottom of `style.css`. Live site is [here](http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/).

Comment: you have not mention
ul#menu-primary-menu li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}

Comment: also dont forget to remove visibility: hidden; from .sub-menu, .sub-menu ul

Comment: Roy, please check [style.css](http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/wp-content/themes/WASCC/style.css) - ul#menu-primary-menu li:hover ul{ display:block; }  is at the bottom. visibility:hidden is removed.

Comment: remove "visibility: hidden: from ".sub-menu, .sub-menu ul"

Comment: Thanks Roy. I can't see why the parent LI element turns black when hovering over it. Can you?

Comment: remove or change the background from "#menu-primary-menu > li:hover, #menu-primary-menu:hover > a"

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your perseverance with me Roy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

here is updated css and html try it may help you

```css
ul#menu-primary-menu > li {
        font-family:Oswald;
        font: 14px/51px Oswald;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #48391f;
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FE8 0%, #fcbb38 100%);
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        position:relative;
        list-style-type : none;
        border-right : #ddd solid 1px;
    }
 ul#menu-primary-menu > li:last-child{
  border-right : none;
  }
    ul#menu-primary-menu > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #48391f;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 20px;
        margin: -10px 0 -10px 0;
    }


.sub-menu li a {
        background: url(/images/dropdown_arrow_white.png) no-repeat center left;
        display: block;
        min-width: 110px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0px 9px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font: 12px/30px Oswald;
    }
    .sub-menu, .sub-menu ul {
        border-top: 3px solid #fcbb38;
        border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -o-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -ms-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: -7px;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 2px;
        top: 38px;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: #333333;
        display: none;
        z-index:999;
    }

    .sub-menu li{
    border-bottom : 2px solid #0063a8;
    }

    .sub-menu li:last-child{
    border-bottom : none;
    }

    ul#menu-primary-menu .sub-menu li a{
      color:#fff;
      text-align : center;
    }
    #menu-primary-menu li .sub-menu li::before {
      content : "\203A";
      position : absolute;
      color : white;
      margin : -11px 0 0 10px;
     }
    ul#menu-primary-menu li:hover .sub-menu{
      display:block;
    }
    
#menu-primary-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
 background : #fcbb38;
 color : #000;
}
Find below updated code which may help you
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" />
<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-67"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/committee/">Committee</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/constitution/">Constitution</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/life-members/">Life Members</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/">Calendar</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-100 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/race-calendar-2016/">Race Calendar 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/">Competition</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/categories/">Categories</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/standing-regs/">Standing Regs</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/licenses/">Licenses</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/results/">Results</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/entries/">Entries</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-87"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/">Membership</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/sign-up-for-membership/">Sign up for Membership</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/gift-cards/">Gift Cards</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-90"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/">Officials</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/accreditations/">Accreditations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/affiliations/">Affiliations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/disciplines/">Disciplines</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might help you

```css
#navigation {
  background: url(http://www.wascc.com.au/Content/themes/base/images/navigation-bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x transparent;
  height: 51px;
  width: 1115px;
}
ul#menu-primary-menu li {
  font: 16px/51px oswaldregular;
  color: #48391f;
  background: url(http://www.wascc.com.au/Content/themes/base/images/navi-shap.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}
ul#menu-primary-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #48391f;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  background: url(/images/dropdown_arrow_white.png) no-repeat center left;
  display: block;
  min-width: 110px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 9px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: 12px/30px oswaldregular;
}
.sub-menu, .sub-menu ul {
  border-top: 3px solid #fcbb38;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #333333;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.menu{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-67"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/">About Us</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/committee/">Committee</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/constitution/">Constitution</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/life-members/">Life Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/">Calendar</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-100 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/race-calendar-2016/">Race Calendar 2016</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/">Competition</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/categories/">Categories</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/standing-regs/">Standing Regs</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/licenses/">Licenses</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/results/">Results</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/entries/">Entries</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-87"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/">Membership</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/sign-up-for-membership/">Sign up for Membership</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/gift-cards/">Gift Cards</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-90"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/">Officials</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/accreditations/">Accreditations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/affiliations/">Affiliations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/disciplines/">Disciplines</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-95"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/">V8 Supercars</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/overview/">Overview</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/travel-information/">Travel Information</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/circuit-map/">Circuit Map</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/v8-supercars/tickets-corporate/">Tickets &amp; Corporate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-73"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/">Activities</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/bike-days/">Bike Days</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/corporate-venue-hire/">Corporate Venue Hire</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/drive-days/">Drive Days</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/karts/">Karts</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/activities/your-car-our-track/">Your Car Our Track</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul#menu-primary-menu > li {
        font-family:Oswald;
        font: 14px/51px Oswald;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #48391f;
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FE8 0%, #fcbb38 100%);
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        position:relative;
        list-style-type : none;
        border-right : #ddd solid 1px;
    }
 ul#menu-primary-menu > li:last-child{
  border-right : none;
  }
    ul#menu-primary-menu > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #48391f;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 20px;
        margin: -10px 0 -10px 0;
    }


.sub-menu li a {
        background: url(/images/dropdown_arrow_white.png) no-repeat center left;
        display: block;
        min-width: 110px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0px 9px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font: 12px/30px Oswald;
    }
    .sub-menu, .sub-menu ul {
        border-top: 3px solid #fcbb38;
        border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -o-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        -ms-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: -7px;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 2px;
        top: 38px;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: #333333;
        display: none;
        z-index:999;
    }

    .sub-menu li{
    border-bottom : 2px solid #0063a8;
    }

    .sub-menu li:last-child{
    border-bottom : none;
    }

    ul#menu-primary-menu .sub-menu li a{
      color:#fff;
      text-align : center;
    }
    #menu-primary-menu li .sub-menu li::before {
      content : "\203A";
      position : absolute;
      color : white;
      margin : -11px 0 0 10px;
     }
    ul#menu-primary-menu li:hover .sub-menu{
      display:block;
    }
    
#menu-primary-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
 background : #fcbb38;
 color : #000;
}
Find below updated code which may help you
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" />
<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-67"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/committee/">Committee</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/constitution/">Constitution</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/about-us/life-members/">Life Members</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/">Calendar</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-100 current_page_item menu-item-102"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/calendar/race-calendar-2016/">Race Calendar 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/">Competition</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/categories/">Categories</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/standing-regs/">Standing Regs</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/licenses/">Licenses</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/results/">Results</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/competition/entries/">Entries</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-87"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/">Membership</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/sign-up-for-membership/">Sign up for Membership</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/membership/gift-cards/">Gift Cards</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-90"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/">Officials</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/accreditations/">Accreditations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/affiliations/">Affiliations</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://test.doig.com.au/wascc/officials/disciplines/">Disciplines</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi @IQBAL. Tried your code, and the parent nav items looked different, and the drop down menus did not work.